# How Does MySQL Store Enums?

Tags: mysql, enums, types

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sizes (
    name ENUM('small', 'medium', 'large')
);
```

Is MySQL going to store those strings in every row, or internally will it use something smaller like integers to know which enum value to refer to?

I want to use an enum in a table but I'm worried if it's as wasteful as storing a string in every row.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It converts them to integers on INSERT / UPDATE and back to strings on SELECT so the internal storage is as integers but you don't get exposed to that.

You can retrieve the integer like `SELECT mycolumn + 0`.

See [ENUMs in MySQL 5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html), enums are stored as values between 0 (no valid value set) and 65,535 that are associated with an enumeration index.  The value that is stored in the table is a 2 byte value, not a string.

Comment: I should add that if the number of enumerations are 255 or less, only **1 byte** is used (similar to TINYINT). (ref: mysql5 docs)

Answer (score 1):

First, I wouldn't worry about space consumption when deciding whether or not to use an enum. Disk space is both plentiful and cheap.

Second, it stores the strings in the column definition and then stores the appropriate enum within each record. According to [this](http://www.making-the-web.com/2008/03/24/saving-bytes-efficient-data-storage-mysql-part-1/) the value stored with each record is a numeric representation of the values position within the enum.

Comment: It's not just space but speed too.  Retrieving a smaller row is faster, and I'd rather JOIN on an enum than a string.

Comment: noah, unless its a mediocre application, otherwise i totally disagree with your first paragraph