# MySQL enum. Is it better to use strings or numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I am curious about MySQL ENUM datatype. 
For example if I have a few possible strings for the field is it better to use a string, or just a number and then to decode the number into a string using for example PHP?

For example:

```
ENUM("Dog", "Cat", "Fish");
```

VS

```
ENUM(1,2,3);
```

and then use something like:

```
<?php
$values = Array("Dog", "Cat", "Fish);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `animal` FROM `example_table`');
$item = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$animal = $item->type;
?>
```

Or is it the best case to use tinyint in such a case where possible entries are fewer than 128(1 byte) ?

I would like to know the advantages/disadvantages in case of performance and space.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL [uses integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259547/how-does-mysql-store-enums) internally for ENUM fields, so it wouldn't make that much of a difference.

The results of [this test](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/) show how fast `ENUM` really is in comparison to VARCHAR or INT with a JOIN to get the string values.

Comment: a specific type of integer: 16 bit unsigned integer, or in mysql-language: `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`

Answer (score 4):

It is fine to use:

```
ENUM("Dog", "Cat", "Fish");
```

Internally MySQL stores enum values as integer. So in this case there is no need to perform extra optimization inside PHP.